# The sign of delta function's gradient when deriving electric displacement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, integration, calculus, dirac-delta-distributions

I got confused when deriving electric displacement $\bf D$ following Wolfgang Nolting's Electrodynamics book. Here is his derivation:

---

[image]

[image]

---

My problem is about integral ① in red. **Property of derivative of delta function** tell us:

$\int{\delta'(x-x_0)f(x)dx = -f'(x_0)}$ and $\delta'(-x)=-\delta'(x)$.

Aware that here ① **integral over r'**, thus should be:

$$\int{d^3r'P(r')·\nabla_{r'}\delta(r-r')} = \int{d^3r'P(r')·-\nabla_{r'}\delta(r'-r) } = -[-\nabla ·P(r)] = \nabla · P(r)$$

Here I got positive sign $\nabla · P(r)$. But why in the book he got negative sign? Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the book you should start by convincing yourself that $\nabla_{\vec r\,'}=-\nabla_{\vec r}$. Then your integral is
$$4\pi\int d^{3}\vec r\,'\vec P(\vec r\,')\cdot\nabla_{\vec r\,'}\delta(\vec r-\vec r\,')=-4\pi\int d^{3}\vec r\,'\vec P(\vec r\,')\cdot\nabla_{\vec r}\delta(\vec r-\vec r\,')$$
Now you can use the identity
$$\nabla\cdot(f\vec A)=f(\nabla\cdot\vec A)+\vec A\cdot\nabla f$$
Note that in this case $\nabla=\nabla_{\vec r}$ and $\vec A=\vec P(\vec r\,')$ such that $\nabla_{\vec r}\cdot \vec P(\vec r\,')=0$. Thus,
$$\nabla_{\vec r}\cdot[\delta(\vec r-\vec r\,')\vec P(\vec r\,')]=\vec P(\vec r\,')\cdot\nabla_{\vec r}\delta(\vec r-\vec r\,')$$
Consequently, the integral is modified to
$$-4\pi\int d^{3}\vec r\,'\nabla_{\vec r}\cdot[\delta(\vec r-\vec r\,')\vec P(\vec r\,')]=-4\pi\nabla_{\vec r}\cdot\int d^{3}\vec r\,'\delta(\vec r-\vec r\,')\vec P(\vec r\,')$$
since the integration is on primed coordinates. The final integral in the above equation equates to $\vec P(\vec r)$ and you end up with $-4\pi\nabla_{\vec r}\cdot \vec P(\vec r)$. I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions or the solution seems incorrect.